# Multiple calling function

Tags: c++

I need add data to my map. I made this function:

```
CSupermarket CSupermarket::Store( string name, CDate x, int count ) {

  pair <CDate, int> p;
  p = make_pair ( x, count );
  vector<pair<CDate, int >>::iterator it;
  vector<pair<CDate, int > > v;
  if ( items[name].size() ) {
    v = items[name];
  }
  it = lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), p );
  v.insert( it, p );
  items[name] = v;
  return * this;
}
```

I have to call it like this:

```
CSupermarket s;
s . Store ( "bread", CDate ( 2016, 4, 30 ), 100 ) .
        Store ( "butter", CDate ( 2016, 5, 10 ), 10 ) .
        Store ( "beer", CDate ( 2016, 8, 10 ), 50 ) .
        Store ( "bread", CDate ( 2016, 4, 25 ), 100 ) .
        Store ( "okey", CDate ( 2016, 7, 18 ), 5 );
s . Store ( "Coke", CDate ( 2016, 12, 31 ), 10 );
```

But when I call this, it adds only items "bread" and "Coke". Please, how I must fix it, that it will add all items ( bread, butter, beer, okey, Coke)?

Thanks

Comment: You need to return CSupermarket by reference from the sort function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is returning a copy of `*this`, and every chained call is creating a new copy.
Only "bread" and "coke" are modifying `s`.

You need to return a reference to `*this`:

```
CSupermarket & CSupermarket::Store( string name, CDate x, int count ) 
             ^
          reference
```